# Index is not getting created, text index required for $text query - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose, indexing

```
mongoose: 5.8.9
node: v12.13.0
```

After setting up to create index on the schema, mongoose doesn't create the index, After creating a new document there is only ID index nothing newly created. I had done as the document mentioned for [creating index](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) but still I can't figure out where I'm making the mistake.

**When**

> ```
>  const ads = await Ad.find({ $text: { $search: "something" } })
> ```

**Error**

```
MongoError: text index required for $text query
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/usama/Projects/commercial/adex/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:466:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at processMessage (/home/usama/Projects/commercial/adex/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:384:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/usama/Projects/commercial/adex/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:553:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:308:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:289:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'text index required for $text query',
  code: 27,
  codeName: 'IndexNotFound',
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

My schema

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose'
import mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2'
import Local from '../index'

const adSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    creater: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: { type: String },
    tags: Array,
    description: { type: String, maxlength: 4500, },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false,
    autoIndex: false
  }
)

adSchema.index({ title: 'text', description: 'text', tags: 'text' })
adSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)

const Ad = Local.model('Ad', adSchema)

export { Ad as default }
```

On mongo shell

```
> myads.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "adex.ads"
    }
]
```

Comment: In your `My schema` what is `Local` ? This `const Ad = Local.model('Ad', adSchema)` has to be `import { Schema, mongoose } from 'mongoose';  const Ad = mongoose.model('Ad', adSchema)`

Comment: On my server, I run two separate MongoDB database, Local runs store data on server remote store on MongoDB atlas

Comment: : Mickl is right, you need to remove autoIndex:false - usually you would enable it for prod servers, I’ve observed it..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below line:

```
adSchema.index({ title: 'text', description: 'text', tags: 'text' })
```

correctly defines an index on mongoose **schema** (not on a database). By default mongoose creates indexes when your application starts up ([link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)) however you're preventing it by using `autoIndex: false`.

So you have to either remove that line or run `createIndexes` on your model explicitly:

```
adSchema.index({ title: 'text', description: 'text', tags: 'text' });
const Ad = Local.model('Ad', adSchema);
Ad.createIndexes();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this creates the `text` index, And what should I do in prod env? should I remove `Ad.createIndexes();` or keep it.

Comment: You can run a one-time script and create all the indexes if you want to have full control over that process or keep Mongoose's autoindexing - it really depends on the deployment strategy you and your organization have

Answer (score 5):

This is how you resolve the same using MongoDB Compass application instead using the mongo console.

Connect to the DB using a connection string like this

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<ip>:<port>/<your db>?authSource=<user>&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false
```

Then select the correct `collection` from the left pane and then select `Indexes` tab and create the text index like shown below

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The best method for me that woks with no warning is from mongodb could

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

and from code you need to pass :>>

```
const blogPosts = await BlogPostModel.find({  $text: { $search: `"${req.query["your-search-query"] }"`  } })
```